# Setting up A5 landscape brochure layout in Illustrator - HOW?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, layout

I have an 8 page brochure to design but I'm using Illustrator instead of InDesign (don't know my way around indesign).

How do I arrange the artboards?

- Do I have the artboards seperately?
- Do I have one long artboard?

What's the best approach to do this?

[image: 8 pages on illustrator]

Comment: Because InDesign is a far superior platform for brochure layout than Illustrator, it would be in your best interest as a designer to learn your way around it (at least for next time). Good luck either way!

Comment: @jason why not do the artwork in Illustrator & import to indesign for final layout? Much easier to control bleeds etc. In InDesign for final printing.

Comment: By 8 pages brochure, do you mean saddle stitch booklet (stapples) or a folded brochure? I often see people calling a booklet a brochure... and I honestly don't know if it's a language thing or using the wrong terms, but to me and everywhere I've worked, a brochure has folds and panels. So what is it? Your graphic looks like a brochure with folds+panels.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter in Illustrator. Layout the artboards however you want.

The only thing which matters is that the artboards are *numbered* in the correct order so when you save as PDF the pages are in the correct order. (but even that can be changed in Acrobat).

Answer (score 0):

If I had to use Illustrator, I would arrange the artboards in two-page spreads. Each spread would have zero gap at the spine, centerfold, etc. Since an 8-page brochure would have a cover, three spreads and a back, I would make the first spread the back/cover, next to the inner cover (usually p# i) and page 1 spread. Below that I would place the page 2-3 next to 4-5 spreads. Don't forget to set your bleeds appropriately.

[image: 8-Page Brochure Layout - Illustrator]

Answer (score 0):

If it is 2up saddle stitch (center stapled), then work with A4 size Artboard with 3mm bleed, make center and outer margins with the help of guidelines, lock them up.

First make a mockup of layout first, take A4 size paper and fold it and staple, then mark as front, front inside, back, back inside and so on....like below

[image]

Hears is an example, done recently

Cover

[image]

hope it will be helpful....